# Create dragable view for selecting screen area for screen recording in mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode5

can anyone give idea me how can i create this type of view. In which i can drag a part of mac screen for screen recording(the image shown below is the only example)

[image]

Comment: There's a sample project by Apple that shows how to record desktop movements.  That's all I can say for now as you don't show any effort you have made so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of thing you need what is called a cover window. 
It's a type of borderless window that happens to take up the full screen. 
Within that you need a draggable and resizable view.

Those are two separate things that can be easily implemented but you will benefit most by doing the rest of the footwork yourself to find out how to code these.

Some keywords that might help. 
NSWindow
NSBorderlessWindowMask
NSView
NSViewController
NSTrackingArea
NSBezierPath
NSRect 
CGRect
NSEvent
NSPoint
CGPoint